# write a condition in SSRS as specified

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to find out how can I write the below logic in SSRS:

The structure of my report is:

[image: Structure]

All the rows and columns are grouped together.

The New Week Status has 2 fields: Current Week and Previous Week.

Current Week ranges from 30th Jan - 5th Feb

Previous Week ranges from 23th Jan - 29th Feb

The Gross Sales is in %.

I need to display only those restaurants where at least 5 days in Current Week and Previous Week is above 2% Gross.

Example:

[image: Example]

In the above example, R1 has more than 5 days > 2%, so it will be displayed

R2 has less than 5 days > 2%, so it won't be displayed

How can the logic be implemented for this?

Comment: How is the Gross Sales being calculated?

Comment: Gross Sales is a inbuilt field in the cube, so I am just fetching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **not** calculating the `Gross Sales` in the report this could work for you.

Select the whole Restaurant row and right click it, select `Row Visibility...` option:

[image]

Select `Show or hide based on an expression:` and use this expression:

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Gross_Sales.Value> 0.02,1,0))>=5,False,True)
```

Now only rows with at least 5 dates that have more than 0.02 (2%) Gross Sales are visible.

**UPDATE:** Adding examples.

I've recreated your dataset and the matrix, so having this structure:

[image]

Using the expression I posted above it hides the `R2` row as expected.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
=IIF(
  SUM(IIF(Fields!Total_Cost.Value/Fields!Sales_Gross.Value>0.02,1,0))>=5
  or
  SUM(IIF(Fields!New_Week_Status.Value = "Current Week" and Fields!Total_Cost.Value/Fields!Sales_Gross.Value>0.02,1,0))>=3
,False,True)
```

Comment: There is a grouping of New Week Status and Full Date...so the mentioned method doesn't work.

Comment: @Shivang, I've recreated your dataset as mentioned in my update. Check you are using the exact same configuration shown in my example.

Comment: I just got to see that my Gross Sales are calculated using TotalCost/SalesGross.   How can I still achieve the solution?

Comment: @Shivang, just use the expression that calculates the `Gross Sales` inside the expression.

Comment: I used:   =IIF(SUM(IIF(  SUM(Fields!Total_Cost.Value)/SUM(Fields!Sales_Gross.Value) > 0.02,1,0))>=5,False,True)     But now nothing is displayed

Comment: @Shivang, I've updated my answer give it a try. Good luck

Comment: Hi, It works  thanks a lot... Now the only last thing remaining is using another condition where 3 days in Current Week is above 2% Gross.. So either this or the above one (the one you gave me solution for) should be displayed in same tablix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135337/discussion-between-shivang-and-alejandro-zuleta).

Comment: @Shivang, just add an additional condition as shown in my last update.

Comment: Thanks a lot,, your solution did the trick!  Very much appreciated